# can't find chrono namespace using mingw32 and Eclipse CDT

Tags: gcc, c++11, mingw32, c++-chrono

I want to use system_clock::time_point, but the compiler can't seem to find
this. I am including  header.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer my own question:

```
#include <chrono>
std::chrono::time_point<std::chrono::system_clock> timePoint;
```